# Which is the preposition to go with “best”? Is it “best at”?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, collocation

Is it right to say:

> We take pride in doing what we are **best at**, delivering unsurpassed levels of service, so our customers can do what they are **best at**.

Comment: Which part of that sentence are you asking about? And what research have you done already?

Comment: the part"best at"

Comment: You are on safe ground. Why did you doubt it? What have you checked out? See  Adrian Doff, Christopher Jones: *Language in Use* p.70 http://books.google.co.in/books?id=rul8Bfnfc1QC&pg=PA70-IA1&lpg=PA70-IA1&dq=%22good+at%22+%22better+at%22+%22best+at%22&source=bl&ots=FL37CmVoo_&sig=X9WleQ-ciYPjEMD6Q6viv18x0l0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PjxMUa_pG4PirAfK3oDoBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22good%20at%22%20%22better%20at%22%20%22best%20at%22&f=false

Comment: *Sarah always had to be **the best at** everything* http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/best?q=best+at+#best__28

Comment: @StJ: Research? A bit hard with so complex a question. This isn't just the 'may a sentence be ended with a preposition' query; it's an appeal (perhaps vaguely understood) for help in deciding whether _be best at_ is totally / partially decomposable. Where would **you** check for that? Have you even considered it? Consider: _This area is fraught with difficulties._  / */? _Think of the difficulties this area is fraught with._ (I've found one relevant Google hit.) If _best at_ is more than a 'free association', why should an adjective+preposition collocation / idiom behave like a preposition?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Incidentally, the OP is not concerned with the issue of ending a sentence with a preposition. That would be digressing from the subject. OP wants to know if *at* is the right preposition that goes with *best* here.

Comment: Is there a site rule saying questions in the OP's body texts (such as _Is it right to say: ..._ can't be taken at face value and addressed - especially in comments? I was under the impression that the fundamental ethos of this site was to discuss the trickier aspects of English, and hopefully to agree on correct usage and to get as close as possible to revealing patterns appearing in structures. It's bad teaching technique to dismiss an over-simplistic question, or, by giving an over-simplistic answer, to miss a chance to at least reveal underlying complexities.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's correct. You could also rephrase it like this:

> We take pride in doing what we *do best*

Comment: Yes, I'd say that's an improvement for the first main clause. It doesn't work too well later on.

Comment: what about "good at" instead of best at

Comment: If you could be honest, the last part should be: _so our customers can do what they are **good for**!_ but being honest is not good for business :)

Comment: Can l use "best for"

Comment: I actually see no problem in ending a sentence with _best at_ (or _good at_) (best for is wrong here), but I would tweak: We take pride in doing what we are best at - delivering unsurpassed levels of service - so that / making sure that our customers can do what _they_ are best at.